# How to configure apport to collect a core dump, but NOT upload it?

Tags: ubuntu, coredump

I'm remotely debugging custom software on a customer's machine. I have already set apport to generate reports for non packaged software.

Can I configure apport to not ask the user to send the report? I don't need or want to submit a bug report containing customer code, but they just click continue when it happens.

If I cannot disable the prompt, can I disable the ability to send the report by changing something in etc/apport/crashdb.conf?

Comment: did you since find out how preventing upload of crash dumps would work?